# Hybrid Raid-1 HDD + SSD -- Write Intent Bitmap

Tags: linux, ssd, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I am currently running a laptop with 1 HDD and 1SSD.

I currently am using `mdadm` to put some partitions in a raid 1 configuration with `--perfer-write` set on the HDD. I have this working correctly however my issue comes with the hard drive spinning down, it never does. I want to be able to run the computer with only the SSD being accessed.

I saw that I can use a write intent bitmap along with deferring writes to allow the HDD to spin down for a while when there is little writing going on however putting this bitmap on the SSD would lead to excess wear along with a performance hit.

I was thinking I could get around this by using an external bitmap and setting it to write to ramfs (arch linux does not have `/dev/ram`. I am going to test the setup in a VM first but can anyone think of potential implications of this approach?

Comment: Potential implications of running the setup in a VM or potential implications of a non-mirrored mirror-raid?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин this was on a laptop. I couldn't end up setting it up for even a test as there was no way to added a write intent bitmap on demand